Using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (\pi,\pi/2)}y\sin(x-y)=\frac{\pi}{2}$
I tried this using $\epsilon$-$\delta$. $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (\pi,\pi/2)}y\sin(x-y)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ For any $\epsilon>0$, we have to find $\delta>0$ s.t. if $0 < \sqrt{\left(x-\pi\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2} < \delta$, then $\left\lvert{y\sin(x-y)-\frac{\pi}{2}}\right\rvert < \epsilon$.
I thought that $$\left\lvert{y\sin(x-y)-\frac{\pi}{2}}\right\rvert < \left\lvert{y-\frac{\pi}{2}}\right\rvert < \sqrt{(x-\pi)^2+\left(y-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2} < \delta,$$ so $$\delta = \epsilon.$$
But $$\left\lvert{y\sin(x-y)-\frac{\pi}{2}}\right\rvert < \left\lvert{y-\frac{\pi}{2}}\right\rvert$$ is not correct.
How should I go about it?

notice that $|y\sin(x-y) - \pi/2| = |y\sin(x-y) - y\sin(\pi-\pi/2) + y\sin(\pi - \pi/2) - \pi/2| \leq |y||sin(x-y) - 1| + |y- \pi/2|$ and proceed from here
